# Docusign sfdc error : List index out of bounds: 0 ,when & how dfsle__EnvelopeStatus__c is created?

Tags: apex, docusign

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String sendEnvelope(String template,String templateName, String description,String title,String companyName,String street,String city,String state,String country,String zip) {
        Id mySourceId = userInfo.getUserId();// The ID of the initiating Salesforce object
        String userName = UserInfo.getFirstName()+' '+UserInfo.getLastName();
        User u=[Select id,LanguageLocaleKey from User  where id=:mySourceId   limit 1];
        String userEmail= UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        List<pf_docusignSignBlock__mdt> docs=[select id,pf_TemplateName__c,Company_Value__c, Company_Translated_Value__c, Name_Value__c, Name_Translated_Value__c, Title_Value__c, Title_Translated_Value__c, By_Value__c, By_Translated_Value__c, Date_Value__c, Date_Translated_Value__c from pf_docusignSignBlock__mdt where pf_TemplateName__c =: templateName    limit 1];
        if(title=='0'){
            title='';
        }
        
        dfsle.Envelope dsEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(
            new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId))
            .withEmail('docusignData ',' '); 
        
        dfsle.Document myDocument =dfsle.Document.fromTemplate(dfsle.UUID.parse(template), description);
        dsEnvelope = dsEnvelope.withDocuments(new List<dfsle.Document> { myDocument });
        
        
        dfsle.CustomField customField = new dfsle.CustomField('list',
                                                              'UseCaseID',
                                                              'Testing_Only', //temporary value only
                                                              new List<String>{'Testing_Only'},
                                                              true,
                                                              true);
        
        dsEnvelope.withCustomFields(new List<dfsle.CustomField>{customField});
        
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor myCompanyLP = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor myCompany = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor myName = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor myTitle = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor mySign = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor myDate = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor myCompanyName = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        dfsle.Tab.Anchor myEmail = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',0,0);
        
        if(docs.isEmpty()){
            myCompanyLP = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('Learning Partner:',false,true,'',true,true,'cms',3,0);
            myCompany = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('Company:', true, true, '',true, true, 'cms',    2, 0);
            myTitle = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('Title:',  true,true,'', true, true, 'cms', 2, 0);
            myName = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('Name:',  true,true,  '',true,true,'cms',2,0);
            mySign = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('By:', true,true,'', true,true,   'mms',  20, 5);
            myDate = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('Date:',false,true,'', true, true, 'cms',2,0);
            myCompanyName = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('Company Name:',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',2,0);
            myEmail = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('Email:',true,true,'',true,true,'cms',2,0);
        }else{
            myCompany = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor(docs[0].Company_Translated_Value__c, true,  true, '', true,true, 'cms', 2,   0);
            myTitle = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor(docs[0].Title_Translated_Value__c, false, true, '',true, true, 'cms', 2, 0);
            myName = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor(docs[0].Name_Translated_Value__c, true, true, '',true,  true, 'cms',  2,0);
            mySign = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor(docs[0].By_Translated_Value__c,  true, true, '', true,true,'mms', 20, 5);
            myDate = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor(docs[0].Date_Translated_Value__c ,  true,   true, '', true,true,  'cms', 2, 0);
            //myCompanyName = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor(getVal.get('Company Name'), true, true,'', true,true,'cms',2, 0);
            //myEmail = new dfsle.Tab.Anchor(getVal.get('Email'), true,true, '', true,  true,'cms', 2,0);
        }
        
        dfsle.Tab myNameTab = new dfsle.TextTab()
            .withReadOnly(true)
            .withRequired(true)
            .withValue(userName)
            .withAnchor(myName)
            .withDataLabel('myname');
        
        
        dfsle.Tab myCompanyTab = new dfsle.TextTab()
            .withReadOnly(true)
            .withRequired(true)
            .withValue(companyName)
            .withAnchor(myCompany)
            .withDataLabel('myCompany');
        
        dfsle.Tab myCompanyNameTab = new dfsle.TextTab()
            .withReadOnly(true)
            .withRequired(true) 
            .withValue(companyName)
            .withAnchor(myCompanyName)
            .withDataLabel('myCompanyName');
        
        dfsle.Tab myCompanyLPTab = new dfsle.TextTab()
            .withReadOnly(true)
            .withRequired(true)
            .withValue(companyName)
            .withAnchor(myCompanyLP)
            .withDataLabel('myCompanyLP');
        
        dfsle.Tab myTitleTab = new dfsle.TextTab()
            .withReadOnly(false)
            .withValue(title)
            .withAnchor(myTitle)
            .withDataLabel('myTitle');
        
        
        dfsle.Tab myEmailTab = new dfsle.TextTab()
            .withRequired(true)
            .withReadOnly(true)
            .withValue(userEmail)
            .withAnchor(myEmail)
            .withDataLabel('myEmail');
        
        
        
        dfsle.Tab mySignHereTab = new dfsle.SignHereTab()
            .withScale(0.5) // 1/2 scale
            .withRequired(true) // Signing mandatory
            .withAnchor(mySign);
        
        
        dfsle.Tab myDateSignedTab = new dfsle.DateSignedTab()
            
            .withAnchor(myDate);
        
        dfsle.Recipient myRecipient=dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner()
            .withTabs(new List<dfsle.Tab> {
                myCompanyNameTab,
                    myCompanyLPTab,
                    myCompanyTab,
                    myNameTab,
                    myEmailTab,
                    mySignHereTab,
                    myTitleTab,
                    myDateSignedTab
                    });
        
        dsEnvelope = dsEnvelope.withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> { myRecipient });
        
        
        
        
        dsEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
            dsEnvelope, // The envelope to send
            true // Send now?
        );
        
        system.debug( String.valueOf(dsEnvelope.docuSignId));
        
        return String.valueOf(dsEnvelope.docuSignId);
        
    }

@AuraEnabled
public static void updateAgreementDetails(string formName,string formVersion) {
    Id mySourceId = userInfo.getUserId();// The ID of the initiating Salesforce object
    list<dfsle__EnvelopeStatus__c> statusList = [SELECT ID, PF_Agreement_Name__c, PF_Agreement_Version__c, PF_Application__c, dfsle__LastStatusUpdate__c, dfsle__Status__c, dfsle__Completed__c FROM dfsle__EnvelopeStatus__c where OwnerId = :mySourceId    order by  dfsle__LastStatusUpdate__c Desc  limit 1];
    statusList[0].PF_Agreement_Name__c = formName;
    statusList[0].PF_Agreement_Version__c = formVersion;       
    update statusList;        
}
```

this a existing code which is failing in only few cases unable to understand why `dfsle__EnvelopeStatus__c` is not created in those cases?

Comment: Some user calls `sendEnvelope`, sending the envelope creates a `dfsle__EnvelopeStatus__c` owned by the same user, but when the same user calls `updateAgreementDetails` afterwards, the record is not found. Is this your line of thought? Have you queried Salesforce manually and checked, if the record exists and is owned by the same user?

Comment: I have checked manually there is no docusign status , i can only see docusign envelope created by the user.

Comment: Does the envelope show a send time? Why do you make the connection from the Envelope Status via the Owner and not a proper lookup?